# How to use the Redirect webpart in sharepoint 2013?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, web-part, redirect

I need to know how to add and use the Redirect web part in SharePoint 2013, Because I need to redirect a SharePoint subsite to site collection, I achieved it by using Script editor web part, Is it possible to achieve this using Redirect web part?

I've tried to refer to this link https://sharepointredirect.codeplex.com/, but it's for 2010, and I am sure how to do the same for 2013. Please suggest some idea achieve this.

Comment: that webpart is developed for SP 2010.. you can go with your script editor approach if you don't need any specific requirement like based on which group etc.. if you have specific requirement you need to handle in client side code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just download [Redirect web part source code](https://sharepointredirect.codeplex.com/downloads/get/282789) then upgrade solution to SharePoint Solution 2013 by doing the following :

- Download the [Redirect web part source code](https://sharepointredirect.codeplex.com/downloads/get/282789)
- Open the solution via Visual Studio , it will ask you to upgrade.

[image]

- The upgrade will be completed without any errors and a little warning

[image]

- Make sure that the Site URL has been changed to your site that you need to deploy the solution
- Try to deploy the solution .
- You will find the deployed web part in custom section.
- Add it to your page , Configure it with your settings
- Now it's found in SharePoint 2013 as shown below:

[image]

**Notes:**

- I did this on my side that working properly without any change in code .
- In Edit Web Part , Set **Status to true** to make the redirect active.
- You already have a WSP that upgraded to SharePont solution 2013 , so you can deploy it in any other Sharepoint 2013 Environment like Production without using visual studio.
- It's expected to get long path error , so don't open the solution from download path, copy it to any drive.
- You may `SANDBOXED CODE HOST SERVICE WAS TOO BUSY TO HANDLE THE REQUEST` this depend on your setting , in my case, I set Sandbox Solution to false.